# Understanding "Trying to get property of non-object" and preventing it

Tags: php, laravel-4

First of all I want to apologies for the thread and I know that there are tons of similar thread on SO. After reading on them I can't really understand what happens in my site. Framework is `Laravel-4.2`

Couple of hours site was okay and everything works perfectly. Now few of the pages get  `Trying to get property of non-object` when I try to access them. **Not all pages.. just 2-3**.

For example this is in my controller to display all orders.

```
public function orders() {

    $orders = Order::select('*')->orderBy('order_id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    return View::make('site.admin.orders', [
        'orders' => $orders
    ]);
}
```

And this is in my view

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $order->order_id }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $order->user->username }}</td>

    // few more <td>`s
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The error is on first `<td>`:

```
<td class="text-center">{{ $order->order_id }}</td>
```

Exact same piece of code works on other site ( copy of this one ). I know in this situation I can just change `$order->order_id` to `$order['order_id']`...

Why is this happen? How to prevent it? I don't understand the nature of this error. And it is very strange to me because this works on exact copy of the site.

Update: This is my **Model**:

```
public function getOrderData($data) {

    $dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($dataArray);
    $arrayKeys = array_filter($arrayKeys, function($value) {
        return ($value !== 'shipping');
    });
    $productIds = implode(',', $arrayKeys);


    $products = DB::table('products')
        ->leftjoin('category', 'products.category_id', '=', 'category.category_id')
        ->leftjoin('sub_category', 'products.sub_cat_id', '=', 'sub_category.sub_cat_id')
        ->where('product_id',$productIds)
        ->get();            

    foreach ($products as $item) {
        if(!in_array($item->product_id, $arrayKeys)) continue;
        $dataArray[$item->product_id]['category'] = $item->category_name;
        $dataArray[$item->product_id]['sub_category'] = $item->sub_cat_name;

    }
    return json_decode(json_encode($dataArray)); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like the Eloquent ORM is juggling between array and object representation of the query results...

Comment: Okay. I've added my Model also. What this mean? How can model 'decide' array or object to use?

Comment: And how come this piece of code to work on site on same server but in different folder. But wont work in another folder? I'm really confused here.

Comment: And I'm sure that object isn't `Null` I have data in database..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “Trying to get property of non-object”, it means you are trying to get
>   something that doesn't exist

. In OOP's classes have object and object have properties associated with them. You can access these properties if they exist.

In your case it doesn't exist. To overcome this use isset() before accessing the values like:

```
isset($order->order_id) ? $order->order_id : 'NA';
```

In this case if the property doesn't exist than code will not throw error, instead it will go in else part and print NA

Comment: Okay, you're correct. I've tried and I've got `NA`. But why? I mean my model pull data from database doesn't this mean that once they are pulled `$orders` had objects? I have 10 orders in database table and if I understand correct this means it's telling me that there is nothing?

Comment: `var_dump($orders)` tight after query returns lot of `object(Illuminate\....` Also all orders from database.

Comment: Ya you have to check this thing also, is the return type is array or object. If it is object than use -> otherwise [] to access the elements

Comment: Okay. I've `truncated` table orders and page working now. Can you explain what happen?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you're trying to access property of something, that is not an object.
For example, if you do something like this

```
$model = MyModel::model()->findByPk('non_existent_primary_key');
```

The `$model` will be `null`, so if you do

```
echo $model->id;
```

you'll get this error.

Comment: Okay. I've truncated table orders and page working now. Can you explain what happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning as orders

```
return View::make('site.admin.orders', [
        'orders' => $orders
    ]);
```

but trying to access with order.